# How to speedup pd.read_csv datetime parsing?

Tags: pandas

I have a csv (sep=' ') file that gets updated every day with 1000 new rows.

YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

It has rows dating back to 2015. It is datetime sorted.
I really only the today's data.

This is the code I use:

```
dprsf = lambda dtstr: datetime.datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
dfigfut = pd.read_csv(fpath, sep=' ', header=None, names=('DateTime', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col5'), parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dprsf, index_col=0)
dfigfut = dfigfut[starttime:endtime]
```

This takes a good amount to parse unneeded rows to just discard them. I suspect most of the gain can be from this.
Next, can the parser be sped up?

Thank you

Comment: With that string format you do not need a lambda call.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_csv(fpath, ...., skiprows=N)` where `N` is the index of last row of the previous day's dataset

Comment: The number of rows is variable unfortunately. I only know if a row is needed after parsing the datetime. Today's rows are needed.

Comment: Parfait, infer didn't work. What's the alternative?

Comment: If you really care only about last day's data, and the number of rows is variable could you maybe:
a) Total number of rows read in a db somewhere? (you can count rows in file manually the first time and start from there) or
b) if you can't do a), just make an assumption and read the file starting at 2019 for example?

Comment: If you're fairly certain of 1000 rows a day are going to be added, you could just read the last 1000+N rows then subset as you have done. Not the cleanest way of doing things but if you have sufficient knowledge of your data source this may be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case of datetime formats and sorted data, you can read the `DateTime` column as strings, do the filtering on strings and only then convert the filtered data to datetime. This gives a speedup of about 10 times:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import timeit
import io

# prepare test data
fpath = 'so57877843.csv'
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('01-01-2015', '09-12-2019', freq='H'))
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(df),5))], axis=1)
df.columns = ['DateTime', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df.to_csv(fpath, sep = ' ', header=None, date_format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", index=False)

# test setup
today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
with open(fpath) as f:
    csv = f.read()  # eliminate disk IO time

def read_date():
   dprsf = lambda dtstr: datetime.datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
   dfigfut = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), sep=' ', header=None, names=('DateTime', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'), parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dprsf, index_col=0)
   dfigfut = dfigfut[dfigfut.index >= today]
   return dfigfut

def read_str():
   dfigfut1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), sep=' ', header=None, names=('DateTime', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'), index_col=0)
   dfigfut1 = dfigfut1[dfigfut1.index >= today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
   dfigfut1.index = pd.to_datetime(dfigfut1.index, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
   return dfigfut1

print(timeit.timeit('read_date()', globals=globals(), number = 10))
print(timeit.timeit('read_str()', globals=globals(), number = 10))

assert(all(read_date() == read_str()))
```

Output (on my machine):

```
10.330610644
1.0750362959999986
```